# VueJS, component hierarchy how to use a component more than once in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a need to use a component more than once in the hierarchy starting with the root component.

Below is the code for the root `Comp1`

```
<template>
  <alert/>
  <modal/>
  <button @click='showAlert()'></button>
</template>
<script>
  import modal from './Modal'
  export default{
    components: {
      modal
    },
    methods: {
      showAlert(){
        //code that shows the alert
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

Below is the code for child component `modal`

```
<template>
  <grandchild/>
</template>
<script>
  import grandchild from './GrandChild'
  export default{
    components: {
      grandchild 
    }
  }
</script>
```

and below is the code for `grandchild`

```
<template>
  <alert/>
  <button @click='showAlert()'></button>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    methods: {
      showAlert(){
        //code that shows the alert
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

`alert` is a modal globally available component with big `z-index` value to make sure it is displayed over other components
When `showAlert()` in `Comp1` is called the alert being displayed is the one in the `modal` component. Why is that happening?

Comment: You really need to give a more concrete example of a) what you have b) what you're trying to achieve and c) where you struggle.
Nobody can help you with this kind of question :D

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References